# Jquery выводит одно и тоже несколько раз

Tags: javascript, jquery

Выводит информацию одну и туже несколько раз в место одного, непонятно из за чего?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.postcode_field').on('keyup change', function () {
    var postcode_field = $(this);
    var form = postcode_field.parents("form");
    var postcode = this.value;
    if (postcode.length == 6) {
      jQuery.ajax({ 
            type : "GET",
            url : '//v_1.php?id='+postcode+'',
            dataType : "json",
        success: function(data){
          postcode_field.val(data.code);          
          if (data.code = postcode) {
              var region = data.region;
              var straat = data.straat;
              var plaats = data.plaats;
              $('<p class=""></p>').html(region +'<br>'+ straat +'<br>'+ plaats).appendTo($("td:last-child", postcode_field.parents("tr")))
          }
        },
        error: function (jqxhr, status, e) {
          var message = "<center><small><font color='#FF0000'>Fout!</font></small></center>"; //+e
          if (e == 'Not Found') message = "<center><small><font color='#FF0000'>Niet gevonden</font></small></center>";
          if (status == 'timeout') message = "<small><font color='#FF0000'>Probeer het opnieuw</font></small>";
          $('<p class=""></p>').html(message).appendTo($("td:last-child", postcode_field.parents("tr")))
          console.debug(jqxhr, status, e);
        },
        complete: function () {
          $("td:last-child p.description.loading", postcode_field.parents("tr")).remove();
        }
      });     
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас прописаны события для keyup и change. Оставьте что-то одно.